# Outlook : Hide automatically the client signature

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins

I'm trying to create an Outlook add-in that creates a new email using the following method:

```
Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm({
    toRecipients: ["firstname.name@email.com"],
    subject: mailSubject,
    htmlBody: mailBody
});
```

But I encountered an issue:

- On the desktop version of Outlook (Windows 10), the new email is created without my signature (that's what I looking for)
- On the OWA version, the new email is created **with** my signature and it appears in the middle of my content (that's really weird).

I want to disable the client signature on the OWA version because it appears inside the message that I want to display in the email (it doesn't appear at the end of the message ...).

Do you know why there are two behaviours between desktop version and OWA?

I saw the following example of a method that allow to disable the client signature but it's only on the Preview version of the Office API: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippets/blob/master/samples/outlook/99-preview-apis/work-with-client-signatures.yaml

I'm running the latest version of the API on OWA (1.9), that's why I need your help.

Thank you

[Edit: 2021/02/01]
Here's my client signature that's set by default when I compose a new email.
[image: Client signature]

Comment: As per our observation:-
1)In OWA , New Email is created using displayNewMessageForm  without signature 
2)In Windows ,New Email is created using displayNewMessageForm  with signature ?
Can you please confirm if behaviour is similar or not for you?

Comment: In OWA, the email is created with the signature but not on Windows version. I use in both cases, the displayNewMessageForm method. I don't want to see the signature when creating a new email.

Comment: As a work around we can disable the signature by removing the Email signature text inside 
Settings > View all Outlook settings > Compose and reply.
I am not able to reproduce this issue ,can you please provide details for reproducible steps and what setting you have changed to enable signature?

Comment: By default, when I compose an email on OWA or on Outlook desktop, my custom signature is displayed.
With the same settings, when I want to create a new email with displayNewMessageForm() method, my signature is not displayed on the Outlook desktop version, but it's displayed on OWA.

Comment: We are not able to reproduce this issue .To investigate further can you please share the format in which you have signature?A screenshot of signature setting will help us .

Comment: I edited my post to share a screenshot of the signature settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I reset my signature and now (with the same parameters as before), the issue seems to be solved. No explanation...

Thanks for you help!